# Can a C callback function be run simultaneously?

Tags: c, function, callback

I am working on raspberry pi camera module interface, and it involves a callback function which you register to the mmal buffer, and it is run each time a frame is grabbed.

My confusion emerges in the case where another frames arrive when the previously running callback function did not finish in time.

Let's imagine we give some loop a callback function, which will be run when a certain event happens. If the callback function that was called with the previous happening of that event, did not yet finish its job, what will happen when the next event arrives? Can same callback function start running (like another thread?) while the previous one is still running?
I doubt it would, but I had to ask to understand.

Comment: What system/API/framework is making the callback? Whatever is making the callback will determine if callbacks can be made in parallel or not.

Answer (score 0):

It could be implemented in different ways.
It could be the case that the frames are stored in a buffer and the function is called on them one after another. This seems to be somewhat like a bounded buffer producer-consumer. Maybe the callback function is a realtime function (they have strict runtime guarantees which ensure the buffer does not overflow) in this case?
Or the function is spawned in a separate thread for each frame. If it's calling the function simultaneously in separate threads, the callback function should be thread-safe.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-safety

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation of the software wich is calling your callback.

The most probable is that it will not launch a thread each time a frame is received and wait the return of the callback before waiting the next frame.

You have too look into the mmal buffer documenattion (and/or codeà to understand how it works and if you need to have thread safe code in your callback.